# org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed because java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to connect to my slack-xmpp service via an Amazon web service. I can run the service locally, but when I try to deploy I get this error:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '<me>.xmpp.slack.com:5222' failed because java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

I'm getting my slack credentials directly from slack. I can do this locally, but as soon as I deploy I'm running into what seems to be a permissions error. Has anyone run into this in the past?

Comment: I am also facing same issue.